# I get a StackOverflowError after I instantiate a class inside itself

Tags: java, error-handling, constructor, stack-overflow, instantiation

I am getting a `StackOverflowError` in line 12 and 65 of this class:

```
package studInfoAndSubj;    // Information Window 

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class StudInfo extends JFrame
{       
    // This Class
    private StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo(); // this is Line 12

    // Subjects Window Class
    private StudSubj studSubj = new StudSubj();

    // Labels
    private JLabel nameL = new JLabel("Student Name: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel snameL = new JLabel("(Surname)", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel fnameL = new JLabel("(First Name)", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel mnameL = new JLabel("(Middle Name)", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel courseL = new JLabel("Course: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel yearL = new JLabel("Year: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel semesterL = new JLabel("Semester: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // Text Fields
    private JTextField snameTF = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField fnameTF = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField mnameTF = new JTextField(10);

    // Text Value Handlers
    private String snameS, fnameS, mnameS, courseS, yearS, semesterS;

    // Buttons
    private JButton nextB = new JButton("Next");
    private JButton cancelB = new JButton("Cancel");
    private NextButtonHandler nextBH = new NextButtonHandler();
    private CancelButtonHandler cancelBH = new CancelButtonHandler();

    // Layouts ((components + rows - 1) / rows)
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    private Container one = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 6));

    // Combo Boxes
    private String[] course = {"BSIT"};
    private String[] year = {"I"};
    private String[] semester = {"1ST", "2ND"};
    private JComboBox<String> courseCB = new JComboBox<>(course);
    private JComboBox<String> yearCB = new JComboBox<>(year);
    private JComboBox<String> semesterCB = new JComboBox<>(semester);

    // Spaces
    private JLabel blank1 = new JLabel(""); 
    private JLabel blank2 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank3 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank4 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank5 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank6 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank7 = new JLabel("");

    // Window Size
    private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    public StudInfo() // and this is line 65
    {
        DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr1 = new DefaultListCellRenderer(); 
        dlcr1.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER); 
        courseCB.setRenderer(dlcr1);
        yearCB.setRenderer(dlcr1);
        semesterCB.setRenderer(dlcr1);
        snameTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        fnameTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        mnameTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        snameL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        fnameL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        mnameL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        nextB.addActionListener(nextBH);
        cancelB.addActionListener(cancelBH);

        Border border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
        courseL.setBorder(border1);
        yearL.setBorder(border1);
        semesterL.setBorder(border1);

        pane.add(one);
        one.add(blank1);
        one.add(nameL);                         
        one.add(snameTF);
        one.add(fnameTF);
        one.add(mnameTF);
        one.add(blank2);
        one.add(blank3);
        one.add(blank4);
        one.add(snameL);
        one.add(fnameL);
        one.add(mnameL);
        one.add(blank5);
        one.add(courseL);
        one.add(courseCB);
        one.add(yearL);
        one.add(yearCB);
        one.add(semesterL);
        one.add(semesterCB);
        one.add(blank6);
        one.add(blank7);
        one.add(cancelB);
        one.add(nextB);

        setTitle("Student Information");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public String getSemValue()
    {
        return semesterS;
    }

    public String[] getSemCBValue()
    {
        return semester;
    }

    private class NextButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            snameS = snameTF.getText();
            fnameS = fnameTF.getText();
            mnameS = mnameTF.getText();
            courseS = courseCB.getSelectedItem().toString();
            yearS = yearCB.getSelectedItem().toString();
            semesterS = semesterCB.getSelectedItem().toString();

            studInfo.setVisible(false);
            studSubj.setVisible(true);

        }

    }

    private class CancelButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo();
}

}
```

And this is my other class:

```
package studInfoAndSubj;    // Subjects Window

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class StudSubj extends JFrame
{       
    // This class
    private StudSubj studSubj = new StudSubj();

    // Information Window Class
    private StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo();

    // Labels
    private JLabel addSubjL = new JLabel("Add Subject: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // Buttons
    private JButton doneB = new JButton("Done");
    private JButton backB = new JButton("Back");
    private DoneButtonHandler doneBH = new DoneButtonHandler();
    private BackButtonHandler backBH = new BackButtonHandler();

    // Text Value Handlers
    private String semesterS = studInfo.getSemValue();
    private String[] semester = studInfo.getSemCBValue();
    private int selectedSubj;
    private String selectedSubjTime;

    // Subject Lists
    private String[] sem1Subj = {"College Algebra\nMWF\n12:00PM-1:00PM", 
                "Communication Arts 1\nMWF\n9:00AM-10:00AM", 
                "Information Technology Fundamentals - Lec\nTTH\n7:30AM-8:30AM", 
                "Information Technology Fundamentals - Lab\nT\n9:00AM-12:00PM", 
                "Programming 1\nMWF\n7:00AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem1AddSubj = {"", "Filipino Christian Living\nMWF\n7:00AM-9:00AM", 
                "Foundation of Physical Education\nTH\n10:00AM-12:00PM", 
                "Komunikasyon sa Akademikong Filipino\nMWF\n9:00AM-10:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2Subj = {"Trigonometry\nMWF\n7:00AM-8:00AM", 
                "Communication Arts 2\nTTH\n9:00AM-10:30AM", 
                "Programming 2\nMWF\n9:00AM-11:00AM", 
                "Database Management Systems\nMWF\n8:00AM-9:00AM", 
                "Network Management\nTTH\n7:30AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2AddSubj = {"", "Environmental Science\nMWF\n8:00AM-9:00AM", 
                "Social Dances\nM\n12:00PM-2:00PM", 
                "General Psychology\nT\n12:00PM-1:00PM"};

    // Subject Time
    private String[] sem1SubjTime = {"MWF12:00PM-1:00PM", "MWF9:00AM-10:00AM", "TTH7:30AM-8:30AM", 
                "T9:00AM-12:00PM", "MWF7:00AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem1AddSubjTime = {"", "MWF7:00AM-9:00AM", "TH10:00AM-12:00PM", "MWF9:00AM-10:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2SubjTime = {"MWF7:00AM-8:00AM", "TTH9:00AM-10:30AM", "MWF9:00AM-11:00AM", 
                "MWF8:00AM-9:00AM", "TTH7:30AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2AddSubjTime = {"", "MWF8:00AM-9:00AM", "M12:00PM-2:00PM", "T12:00PM-1:00PM"};

    // Layouts ((components + rows - 1) / rows)
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    private Container two = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

    // Combo Boxes
    private JComboBox<String> sem1AddSubjCB = new JComboBox<>(sem1AddSubj);
    private JComboBox<String> sem2AddSubjCB = new JComboBox<>(sem2AddSubj);

    // Window Size
    private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    public StudSubj() 
    {
        DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr2 = new DefaultListCellRenderer(); 
        dlcr2.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER); 
        sem1AddSubjCB.setRenderer(dlcr2);
        sem2AddSubjCB.setRenderer(dlcr2);

        doneB.addActionListener(doneBH);
        backB.addActionListener(backBH);

        // 1st Semester Subjects
        JLabel sem1Subj1 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[0]);
        JLabel sem1Subj2 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[1]);
        JLabel sem1Subj3 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[2]);
        JLabel sem1Subj4 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[3]);
        JLabel sem1Subj5 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[4]);

        // 2nd Semester Subjects
        JLabel sem2Subj1 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[0]);
        JLabel sem2Subj2 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[1]);
        JLabel sem2Subj3 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[2]);
        JLabel sem2Subj4 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[3]);
        JLabel sem2Subj5 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[4]);

        Border border2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
        sem1Subj1.setBorder(border2);   sem2Subj1.setBorder(border2);
        sem1Subj2.setBorder(border2);   sem2Subj2.setBorder(border2);
        sem1Subj3.setBorder(border2);   sem2Subj3.setBorder(border2);
        sem1Subj4.setBorder(border2);   sem2Subj4.setBorder(border2);
        sem1Subj5.setBorder(border2);   sem2Subj5.setBorder(border2);
        addSubjL.setBorder(border2);

        pane.add(two);

        if(semesterS.equals(semester[0]))
        {
            setTitle("(BSIT - I - 1st Semester) List Of Subjects");
            two.add(sem1Subj1);
            two.add(sem1Subj2);
            two.add(sem1Subj3);
            two.add(sem1Subj4);
            two.add(sem1Subj5);
            two.add(addSubjL);
            two.add(sem1AddSubjCB);

        }else if(semesterS.equals(semester[1]))
        {
            setTitle("(BSIT - I - 2nd Semester) List Of Subjects");
            two.add(sem2Subj1);
            two.add(sem2Subj2);
            two.add(sem2Subj3);
            two.add(sem2Subj4);
            two.add(sem2Subj5);
            two.add(addSubjL);
            two.add(sem2AddSubjCB);

        }

            two.add(backB);
            two.add(doneB);

            setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        }

        private class DoneButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int ctr;

                if(semesterS.equals(semester[0]))
                {
                    selectedSubj = sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex();
                    selectedSubjTime = sem1AddSubj[selectedSubj];

                    for(ctr = 0; ctr <= sem1AddSubj.length; ctr++)
                    {
                        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem1AddSubjTime[ctr]))
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);

                        }else{
                            sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();

                        }

                    }

                }else if(semesterS.equals(semester[1]))
                {
                    selectedSubj = sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex();
                    selectedSubjTime = sem2AddSubj[selectedSubj];

                    for(ctr = 0; ctr <= sem1AddSubj.length; ctr++)
                    {

                        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem2AddSubjTime[ctr]))
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);

                        }else{
                            sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();

                        }
                    }

                }
            }   
        }

        private class BackButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                studSubj.setVisible(false);
                studInfo.setVisible(true);

            }

        }


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    StudSubj studSubj = new StudSubj();
}

}
```

This error appears when I run `main`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
>       at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Frame.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Frame.(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JFrame.(Unknown Source)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:65)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:12)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:12)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:12)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:12)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:12)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:12)
>       at studInfoAndSubj.StudInfo.(StudInfo.java:12)

Why is this happening? Can I fix it?

Comment: `private static StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo();`?

Comment: @saka1029 i tried that the StackOverFlow error was solved but now it says A java Exception has occured, ExceptionInitializerError and a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said you are creating too many instances of `StudInfo` but even once that is fixed you will get many more exceptions. To fix your problems see the amended code.

**StudInfo.java**

```
package studInfoAndSubj;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class StudInfo extends JFrame {

    private StudSubj sJ;

    // Labels
    private JLabel nameL = new JLabel("Student Name: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel snameL = new JLabel("(Surname)", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel fnameL = new JLabel("(First Name)", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel mnameL = new JLabel("(Middle Name)", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel courseL = new JLabel("Course: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel yearL = new JLabel("Year: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel semesterL = new JLabel("Semester: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // Text Fields
    private JTextField snameTF = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField fnameTF = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField mnameTF = new JTextField(10);

    // Text Value Handlers
    private String snameS, fnameS, mnameS, courseS, yearS, semesterS;

    // Buttons
    private JButton nextB = new JButton("Next");
    private JButton cancelB = new JButton("Cancel");
    private ButtonHandler bH = new ButtonHandler();

    // Layouts ((components + rows - 1) / rows)
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    private Container one = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 6));

    // Combo Boxes
    private String[] course = {"BSIT"};
    private String[] year = {"I"};
    private String[] semester = {"1ST", "2ND"};
    private JComboBox<String> courseCB = new JComboBox<>(course);
    private JComboBox<String> yearCB = new JComboBox<>(year);
    private JComboBox<String> semesterCB = new JComboBox<>(semester);

    // Spaces
    private JLabel blank1 = new JLabel(""); 
    private JLabel blank2 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank3 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank4 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank5 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank6 = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel blank7 = new JLabel("");

    // Window Size
    private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    public StudInfo() // and this is line 65
    {
        DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr1 = new DefaultListCellRenderer(); 
        dlcr1.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER); 
        courseCB.setRenderer(dlcr1);
        yearCB.setRenderer(dlcr1);
        semesterCB.setRenderer(dlcr1);
        snameTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        fnameTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        mnameTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        snameL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        fnameL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        mnameL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        nextB.addActionListener(bH);
        cancelB.addActionListener(bH);

        Border border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
        courseL.setBorder(border1);
        yearL.setBorder(border1);
        semesterL.setBorder(border1);

        pane.add(one);
        one.add(blank1);
        one.add(nameL);                         
        one.add(snameTF);
        one.add(fnameTF);
        one.add(mnameTF);
        one.add(blank2);
        one.add(blank3);
        one.add(blank4);
        one.add(snameL);
        one.add(fnameL);
        one.add(mnameL);
        one.add(blank5);
        one.add(courseL);
        one.add(courseCB);
        one.add(yearL);
        one.add(yearCB);
        one.add(semesterL);
        one.add(semesterCB);
        one.add(blank6);
        one.add(blank7);
        one.add(cancelB);
        one.add(nextB);

        setTitle("Student Information");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sJ = new StudSubj(this);
    }

    public String getSemValue()
    {
        return semesterS;
    }

    public String[] getSemCBValue()
    {
        return semester;
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == nextB) {
                snameS = snameTF.getText();
                fnameS = fnameTF.getText();
                mnameS = mnameTF.getText();
                courseS = courseCB.getSelectedItem().toString();
                yearS = yearCB.getSelectedItem().toString();
                semesterS = semesterCB.getSelectedItem().toString();


                setVisible(false);
                sJ.build();
            } else if(e.getSource() == cancelB) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo();
    }
}
```

**StudSubj.java**

```
package studInfoAndSubj;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class StudSubj extends JFrame {

    private StudInfo sI;

    // Labels
    private JLabel addSubjL = new JLabel("Add Subject: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // Buttons
    private JButton doneB = new JButton("Done");
    private JButton backB = new JButton("Back");
    private ButtonHandler bH = new ButtonHandler();

    // Text Value Handlers
    private String semesterS;
    private String[] semester;
    private int selectedSubj;
    private String selectedSubjTime;

    // Subject Lists
    private String[] sem1Subj = {"College Algebra\nMWF\n12:00PM-1:00PM", 
    "Communication Arts 1\nMWF\n9:00AM-10:00AM", 
    "Information Technology Fundamentals - Lec\nTTH\n7:30AM-8:30AM", 
    "Information Technology Fundamentals - Lab\nT\n9:00AM-12:00PM", 
    "Programming 1\nMWF\n7:00AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem1AddSubj = {"", "Filipino Christian Living\nMWF\n7:00AM-9:00AM", 
    "Foundation of Physical Education\nTH\n10:00AM-12:00PM", 
    "Komunikasyon sa Akademikong Filipino\nMWF\n9:00AM-10:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2Subj = {"Trigonometry\nMWF\n7:00AM-8:00AM", 
    "Communication Arts 2\nTTH\n9:00AM-10:30AM", 
    "Programming 2\nMWF\n9:00AM-11:00AM", 
    "Database Management Systems\nMWF\n8:00AM-9:00AM", 
    "Network Management\nTTH\n7:30AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2AddSubj = {"", "Environmental Science\nMWF\n8:00AM-9:00AM", 
    "Social Dances\nM\n12:00PM-2:00PM", 
    "General Psychology\nT\n12:00PM-1:00PM"};

    // Subject Time
    private String[] sem1SubjTime = {"MWF12:00PM-1:00PM", "MWF9:00AM-10:00AM", "TTH7:30AM-8:30AM", 
    "T9:00AM-12:00PM", "MWF7:00AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem1AddSubjTime = {"MWF7:00AM-9:00AM", "TH10:00AM-12:00PM", "MWF9:00AM-10:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2SubjTime = {"MWF7:00AM-8:00AM", "TTH9:00AM-10:30AM", "MWF9:00AM-11:00AM", 
    "MWF8:00AM-9:00AM", "TTH7:30AM-9:00AM"};
    private String[] sem2AddSubjTime = {"MWF8:00AM-9:00AM", "M12:00PM-2:00PM", "T12:00PM-1:00PM"};

    // Layouts ((components + rows - 1) / rows)
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    private Container two = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

    // Combo Boxes
    private JComboBox<String> sem1AddSubjCB = new JComboBox<>(sem1AddSubj);
    private JComboBox<String> sem2AddSubjCB = new JComboBox<>(sem2AddSubj);

    // Window Size
    private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    private JLabel sem1Subj1 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[0]);
    private JLabel sem1Subj2 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[1]);
    private JLabel sem1Subj3 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[2]);
    private JLabel sem1Subj4 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[3]);
    private JLabel sem1Subj5 = new JLabel(sem1Subj[4]);

    // 2nd Semester Subjects
    private JLabel sem2Subj1 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[0]);
    private JLabel sem2Subj2 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[1]);
    private JLabel sem2Subj3 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[2]);
    private JLabel sem2Subj4 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[3]);
    private JLabel sem2Subj5 = new JLabel(sem2Subj[4]);

    public StudSubj(StudInfo sI) 
    {
        this.sI = sI;

        DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr2 = new DefaultListCellRenderer(); 
        doneB.addActionListener(bH);
        backB.addActionListener(bH);
        dlcr2.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER); 
        sem1AddSubjCB.setRenderer(dlcr2);
        sem2AddSubjCB.setRenderer(dlcr2);

        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Border border2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
        sem1Subj1.setBorder(border2);
        sem2Subj1.setBorder(border2);

        sem1Subj2.setBorder(border2); 
        sem2Subj2.setBorder(border2);

        sem1Subj3.setBorder(border2);   
        sem2Subj3.setBorder(border2);

        sem1Subj4.setBorder(border2);   
        sem2Subj4.setBorder(border2);

        sem1Subj5.setBorder(border2);   
        sem2Subj5.setBorder(border2);

        addSubjL.setBorder(border2);
    }

    public void build() {
        pane.add(two);

        semesterS = sI.getSemValue();
        semester = sI.getSemCBValue();

        if(semesterS.equals(semester[0])) {
            setTitle("(BSIT - I - 1st Semester) List Of Subjects");
            two.add(sem1Subj1);
            two.add(sem1Subj2);
            two.add(sem1Subj3);
            two.add(sem1Subj4);
            two.add(sem1Subj5);
            two.add(addSubjL);
            two.add(sem1AddSubjCB);

        } else if(semesterS.equals(semester[1])) {
            setTitle("(BSIT - I - 2nd Semester) List Of Subjects");
            two.add(sem2Subj1);
            two.add(sem2Subj2);
            two.add(sem2Subj3);
            two.add(sem2Subj4);
            two.add(sem2Subj5);
            two.add(addSubjL);
            two.add(sem2AddSubjCB);
        }

        two.add(backB);
        two.add(doneB);

        repaint();
        revalidate();

        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == doneB) {
                int ctr;

                if(semesterS.equals(semester[0]))
                {
                    selectedSubj = sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex()-1;
                    selectedSubjTime = sem1AddSubjTime[selectedSubj];

                    for(ctr = 0; ctr < sem1SubjTime.length; ctr++)
                    {
                        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem1SubjTime[ctr])) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);
                        } else {
                        sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();
                        }

                    }

                } else if(semesterS.equals(semester[1])) {
                    selectedSubj = sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex()-1;
                    selectedSubjTime = sem2AddSubjTime[selectedSubj];

                    for(ctr = 0; ctr < sem2SubjTime.length; ctr++)
                    {

                        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem2SubjTime[ctr]))
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);
                        } else {
                            sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if(e.getSource() == backB) {
                setVisible(false);
                sI.setVisible(true);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

*Note: I removed the `main function` from the `StudSubj` class so you need to run `StudInfo` to make it work*

Changelog, apologies for not making the changes clear.

- There is now only one instance of each class and they switch between each other when the correct buttons are clicked.
- In each class there were two `Action Listeners` whereas now there is only one which identifies which `JButton` fired the `Action Event` and then follows out the code accordingly. This is done with `e.getSource()`.
- Created a new function, `build()` so that when `nextB` is clicked it takes the latest values selected in the `JComboBoxes`
- Slightly modified the arrays `sem1AddSubjTime` and `sem2AddSubjTime` and changed

*Original*

```
int ctr;

if(semesterS.equals(semester[0]))
{
    selectedSubj = sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex();
    selectedSubjTime = sem1AddSubj[selectedSubj];

    for(ctr = 0; ctr <= sem1AddSubj.length; ctr++)
    {
        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem1AddSubjTime[ctr]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);

        }else{
            sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();

        }

    }

}else if(semesterS.equals(semester[1]))
{
    selectedSubj = sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex();
    selectedSubjTime = sem2AddSubj[selectedSubj];

    for(ctr = 0; ctr <= sem1AddSubj.length; ctr++)
    {

        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem2AddSubjTime[ctr]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);

        }else{
            sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();

        }
    }

}
```

*Modified*

```
int ctr;

if(semesterS.equals(semester[0]))
{
    selectedSubj = sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex()-1;
    selectedSubjTime = sem1AddSubjTime[selectedSubj];

    for(ctr = 0; ctr < sem1SubjTime.length; ctr++)
    {
        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem1SubjTime[ctr])) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);
        } else {
        sem1AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();
        }

    }

} else if(semesterS.equals(semester[1])) {
    selectedSubj = sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedIndex()-1;
    selectedSubjTime = sem2AddSubjTime[selectedSubj];

    for(ctr = 0; ctr < sem2SubjTime.length; ctr++)
    {

        if(selectedSubjTime.equals(sem2SubjTime[ctr]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choosen Subject has same time with the others!", "Error", 0);
        } else {
            sem2AddSubjCB.getSelectedItem();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You left out some functionality in his code... It would be good if you explained exactly *what* you changed and *why* you changed it.

Comment: I shall update my answer but what functionality did I leave out?

Comment: Maybe I'm just looking carelessly, but it seems that BackButtonHandler is missing... I'm not sure what else but it's hard to tell since they are such big pieces of code

Comment: @Idos Ah I just put the handlers together in one handler for each file. But your right I will explain what I did fully in a an edit

Comment: @Idos Included a changelog

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
private StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo();
```

Which is called from `main`:

```
StudSubj studSubj = new StudSubj();
```

Creates a new `StudInfo` object, which has a field of the same type.

When the first instance of `StudInfo` is created, the *other* one is instantiated as well. That one *also* has a field that instantiates *yet another* `StudInfo`, and so on...

This would go on forever if a `StackOverflowError` wasn't thrown.
You need to avoid creating an object of the class itself as a member or field.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue consist trying to instance the `StudInfo` class two times in:

```
    private StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo(); // this is Line 12
```

And in:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    StudInfo studInfo = new StudInfo();
   }
```